# Comparing asymptotic complexity of functions $\log{n}$, $(\log{n})^c$ and $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: asymptotics

I usually follow approach of taking logs and putting arbitrary large powers of $2$ for $n$ and reducing the given function to some constant value for large value of $n$. So in this case I did it as follows:

- $\log{n}$

  Putting $n=2^{2^{2^{16}}}$ and taking $\log$

  $\log{\log(2^{2^{2^{16}}})}={2^{16}}$

  ---
- $(\log{n})^c$

  Putting $n=2^{2^{2^{16}}}$, $c=2$ and taking $\log$

  $\log({(\log{2^{2^{2^{16}}}})^2})=\log({2\times(\log{2^{2^{2^{16}}}})})=\log({2\times(2^{2^{16}})})=\log{2}\times\log{2^{2^{16}}}$

  $=1+2^{16}$

  ---
- $\sqrt{n}$

  Putting $n=2^{2^{2^{16}}}$ and taking $\log$

  $\log{\sqrt{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}}=\log{2^{2^{2^{{16}^{\frac{1}{2}}}}}}=\log{2^{2^{2^8}}}=2^{2^8}=2^{16}$

So it looks like:

$\log{n}=\sqrt{n}<(\log {n})^c$

However I checked that $\log{8}>\sqrt{8}$. But, $\log{(2^{2^{2^{16}}})}=64$, whereas $\sqrt{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}$ is much larger number making equality between the two unlikely.

1. So where I am making mistakes in above calculations?
2. How above three functions compare asymptotically?

Comment: Your approach simply isn't valid. You have just demonstrated it.

Comment: In addition to your method not being valid (though it works fine as a heuristic I guess), you didn't apply it correctly. $\sqrt{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}$ is $2^{\left(\frac{1}{2} 2^{2^{16}}\right)}$, not $2^{2^{2^{\left(\frac{1}{2} 16\right)}}}$.

Comment: @CraigGidney are you sure ? is [this](http://s19.postimg.org/x7n2g3c0j/math_stx.png) wrong?

Comment: @anir That calculator seems to be computing $((2^2)^2)^{16}$ instead of $2^{(2^{(2^{16})})}$. Conventionally, $2^{2^{2^{16}}}$ refers to $2^{(2^{(2^{16})})}$. If you intended $((2^2)^2)^{16}$, then the actual problem in your evaluation is that $\lg(((2^2)^2)^{16}) = 16 \lg((2^2)^2) = 64$, which is not the $(2^2)^{16}$ you assumed.

Comment: I feel I made huge mistakes above. Putting $n={2^{2^{2^{16}}}}$, $c=2$ & taking $log$, we get: **(f1)** $\log_2 n →\log_2 \log_2 {2^{2^{2^{16}}}}=2^{16}$ **(f2)** $(log_2 n)^c →\log_2 ((\log_2 {2^{2^{2^{16}}}})^2)=2×\log_2(\log_2(2^{2^{2^{16}}}))=2×2^{16}=2^{17}$ **(f3)** $\sqrt{n}→\log_2((2^{2^{2^{16}}})^{0.5})=0.5×\log_2(2^{2^{2^{16}}})=0.5×2^{2^{16}}=\frac{2^{65536}}{2}=2^{65535}$. So, $(f1)<(f2)<(f3)$ giving $f1=o(f2)$ & $(f2)=o(f_3)$. Can you please confirm if this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any $c>1,\epsilon>0$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log n)^c}{n^\epsilon} = 0$$

This means that $\log n=o( (\log n)^c)$ and $(\log n)^c = o(n^\epsilon)$. In particular, for $\epsilon =0.5$, $(\log n)^c = o(\sqrt{n})$.

See [Reference answers to frequently asked questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846)